# Update column value modified from another user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called Note, roleName and there are two roles, admin and engineer.
The engineer updates the notes and saves it , at the same time when admin logs in and modifies the same record (notes), he should be able to do it. How can I achieve this using case sql?

Comment: What do you mean by "case sql"? What you have here is an issue known as concurrency. This is not a non-trivial thing as the complexity can get pretty intense for these kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

If two users update the same field in the same table, then the user which updates last, will win. If you are trying to do something like Google Docs, where many users can update the same data, that is going to be more than just a update to a table.